# onBlur event fires on every tab in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, wcag

I wonder if there is another way of monitoring if a user leaves a `<div>`? Because when I tab trough the under menu below, the onBlur event is fired for every tab. What I want to acheive is that I can set open to false when the user have tabed trough the submenu. What is the correct way?

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan how did you create this message? It is auto-generated, or you copy-paste it?

Comment: @Anton https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Comment: The text I use is : Please visit the `[help]`, take the `[tour]` to see what and `[ask]`. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a `[mcve]` of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the \`[<>]\` snippet editor.